# Яндекс геокодер номер дома не всегда приходит

Tags: яндекс-карты, геокодирование

Использую карту на сайте для получения адреса по координатам который вводит пользователь тыкая на карту. К сожалению не всегда удаётся получить номер дома по введённым долготе и ширине для посёлков. Например https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=36.454229,55.807213&format=json

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете самостоятельно заполнить адрес этого дома тут https://n.maps.yandex.ru/#!/objects/1656513041?z=19&ll=36.454405%2C55.807134&l=nk%23sat и он будет находиться по координатам.